# SWIFT: How to load local images remote HTML

Tags: ios, swift

Currently I'm developing an app for Android and iOS. It is a simple webView which is calling a remote URL.

This works perfectly fine - but now I have a problem figuring out how to intercept the loading of images.
I'm trying to achieve the following:
 * Load remote URL
 * Intercept load and check for images
 * If the image exists within the app (in a certain folder) load the local image, otherwise load the remote image from the server

On Android it is pretty easy:

```
public WebResourceResponse shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, String url) {
        try {
            if( url.endsWith("png") ) {
                return new WebResourceResponse("image/png", "ISO-8859-1", ctx.getAssets().open(url.substring(basepath.length())));
            }
            if( url.endsWith("jpg") ) {
                return new WebResourceResponse("image/jpg", "ISO-8859-1", ctx.getAssets().open(url.substring(basepath.length())));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return super.shouldInterceptRequest(view, url);
    }
```

On iOS - especially SWIFT I haven't found a solution to it yet. So far this is what I have for my webView:

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!
var urlpath = "http://stackoverflow.com"
func loadAddressURL(){
   let requesturl = NSURL(string: urlpath!)
   let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requesturl)
   webView.loadRequest(request) }

override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   loadAddressURL() }
```

Could anyone point me into the correct direction on how to achieve the above mentioned result?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using [`NSURLProtocol`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLProtocol_Class/index.html), here's a quick example:

1. Subclass `NSURLProtocol`

   ```
   class Interceptor: NSURLProtocol {
       override class func canonicalRequestForRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> NSURLRequest {
           return request
       }

       override class func canInitWithRequest(request: NSURLRequest) -> Bool {
           // returns true for the requests we want to intercept (*.png)
           return request.URL.pathExtension == "png"
       }

       override func startLoading() {
           // a request for a png file starts loading
           // custom response
           let response = NSURLResponse(URL: request.URL, MIMEType: "image/png", expectedContentLength: -1, textEncodingName: nil)

           if let client = self.client {
               client.URLProtocol(self, didReceiveResponse: response, cacheStoragePolicy: .NotAllowed)

               // reply with data from a local file
               client.URLProtocol(self, didLoadData: NSData(contentsOfFile: "local file path")!)

               client.URLProtocolDidFinishLoading(self)
           }
       }

       override func stopLoading() {
       }
   }
   ```
2. Somewhere in your code, register the `Interceptor` class:

   ```
   NSURLProtocol.registerClass(Interceptor)
   ```

There's also a nice article on [`NSHipster`](http://nshipster.com/nsurlprotocol/) if you want to read more about `NSURLProtocol`.

Comment: Hi @pNre , with subclassing NSURLProtocol, how would you handle the fact you want some request to be handle like this and sometimes differently (say you want some request being cached while other not)?

Comment: what if you wanted to allow all image mime types?  png jpg tiff etc how would you apply a filter?